# Show that $\{\cup_{n\in K} (n, n+1]: K \subset \mathbb{Z}\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: measure-theory, proof-writing

I am trying to prove that $\mathcal{S} = \{\cup_{n\in K} (n, n+1]: K \subset \mathbb{Z}\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$ using the definition.

I want to show two things: (1) $E \in \mathcal{S} \implies E^c \in \mathcal{S}$ and (2) If $E_1, E_2, \dots$ is a sequence of members of $\mathcal{S}$, then $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty E_i\in\mathcal{S}$.

**My attempt**: Fix $K \subset \mathbb{Z}$. Let $E\in\mathcal{S}$. Then, $E=\bigcup_{n\in K}(n, n+1]$. So, $E^c = \bigcap_{n\in K} (-\infty, n]\cup (n+1, \infty)$. Now, how can I show that $E^c\in\mathcal{S}$? It seems that as $n$ increases, the intervals that constitute $E^c$ get smaller and smaller, so the intersection of all these intervals would get smaller and smaller. Also, how can (2) be proven? Would be have $2$ unions in this part?

Comment: Don’t use DeMorgan’s law: try to write $E^c$ as in the form $\bigcup_{n\in L}(n,n+1]$; there is an easy way to get $L$ from $K$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I think that I can write $E^c=\cup_{n \in K} (-\infty, n]\cup(n+1, \infty)$. Is this the form I should be using?

Comment: Just a comment: $K$ is not fixed, $K$ depends on $E$. So, you should start the proof by saying something like "Let $E \in \mathcal S$. Then there exists $K \subset \mathbb Z$ such that $E = \bigcup_{n \in K}(n,n+1]$."

Comment: @Ricky_Nelson: No; that is simply wrong, since that union is not equal to $E$. It also isn’t at all like my suggestion.

Comment: @azif00 Thanks! I wasn't sure how I should have approached that part of the proof!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\mathbb{R} = \bigcup\limits_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} (n, n + 1]$, so the purported $\sigma$-algebra has the whole space as an element. In fact, note that every element of $\mathbb{R}$ is in exactly one of the sets of the form $(n, n + 1]$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

It follows that the complement of the set $\bigcup\limits_{k \in K} (k, k + 1]$ is the set $\bigcup\limits_{k \in \mathbb{Z} - K} (k, k + 1]$. Thus, the purported $\sigma$-algebra is closed under complements.

Finally, if we take $\bigcup\limits_{i = 1}^\infty \bigcup\limits_{k \in K_i} (k, k + 1]$, this is clearly equal to $\bigcup\limits_{k \in K} (k, k + 1]$ where we define $K = \bigcup\limits_{i = 1}^\infty K_i$. So the purported $\sigma$-algebra is closed under countable union.

Thus, the purported $\sigma$-algebra actually is a $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: Would your proof hold if $K$ is a strict subset of the set of integers?

Comment: @Ricky_Nelson If you require $K$ to be a strict subset of $\mathbb{Z}$ in the definition $S = \{\bigcup\limits_{k \in K} (k, k + 1] : K \subset \mathbb{Z}\}$, then the result is not a $\sigma$-algebra because $\mathbb{R} \notin S$.