# Verifying that $\mathcal{S}=\{\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{K}}(n,n+1]:K\subset\mathbb{Z}\}$ is a sigma-algebra on $\mathbb{R} $

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

I have proved the following statement and I would like to know if I have made any mistakes, thanks.

"$\mathcal{S}=\{\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{K}}(n,n+1]:K\subset\mathbb{Z}\}$ is a sigma-algebra on $\mathbb{R} $"

My proof$^*$:

To see that $\emptyset\in S$ it is enough to take $K=\emptyset\subset\mathbb{Z}$ and remember that the union over the empty set is empty, i.e. $\bigcup_{n\in\emptyset}(n,n+1]=\emptyset$.

Now, let $E\in S$: then $E=\bigcup_{n\in K}(n,n+1]$ so $$E^c=(\bigcup_{n\in K}(n,n+1])^c=\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{K}} (-\infty,n]\cup (n+1,\infty]=\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{K}} \mathbb{R}\setminus(n,n+1]=\mathbb{R}\setminus\bigcup_{n\in K}(n,n+1]=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}(n,n+1]\setminus\bigcup_{n\in K}(n,n+1]=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus K\subset\mathbb{Z}}(n,n+1]\in S$$ where the second to last inequality follows from the identity $\bigcap_i A\setminus B_i=A\setminus\bigcup_i B_i$ and the last one from the fact that $\mathbb{R}=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}(n,n+1]$ (clearly, $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}(n,n+1]\subset\mathbb{R}$; if $x\in\mathbb{R}$ then $[x]\leq x\leq [x]+1$ so if $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ then $x=[x]$ and by setting $n_x:=[x]-1$ we have that $x\in (n_x,n_x+1]\subset\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}(n,n+1]$; if $x\notin\mathbb{Z}$ then $[x]<x\leq [x]+1$ so if we set $n_x:=[x]$ we have that $x\in (n_x,n_x+1)\subset\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}(n,n+1]$ hence $\mathbb{R}\subset\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}(n,n+1]$ too).

Let $E_1, E_2,\dots$ be a sequence of elements of $S$: then $E_1=\bigcup_{n\in K_1}(n,n+1], E_2=\bigcup_{n\in K_2}(n,n+1], \dots $so if we take $K_{TOT}=\bigcup_{j\geq 1} K_j\subset\mathbb{Z}$ we have that $\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty E_k=\bigcup_{n \in K_{TOT}}(n,n+1]\in S$, as desired, and this concludes the proof.

---

$^*$(the observation that $\mathbb{R}=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}(n,n+1]$ which has helped me in proving the second requirement is due to user Mark Saving)

Comment: $K$ need not be a finite set.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show that $\{\cup_{n\in K} (n, n+1]: K \subset \mathbb{Z}\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4057149/show-that-cup-n-in-k-n-n1-k-subset-mathbbz-is-a-sigma-algeb)

Comment: @azif00 it has helped me for part 2. I would like to know parts 1 and 2 are also correct.